# Timeout error (request expired) at Android app + Laravel backend

Tags: javascript, android, laravel, android-studio

i'm working on a taxi project (like uber) 2 android apps for driver/user and a Laravel backend

I have a severe problem. Many devs have tried to solve it without success.

Sometimes the ride is canceled itself!!

I try the two apps on two different phones.. I request a ride and accept it, etc.. It often works without a problem. But sometimes this problem occurs. Either during the trip or when the trip ends, I don't click on the payment confirmation button, but wait for a minute or two...sometimes the problem happens. So the trip is canceled on its own, and also the driver doesn't appear anymore on the user's map screen until I go offline then online again at driver app.

The error message that appears on the driver application when trip canceled is **request _time_out**

```js
    public void cancelRequest(String id, String reason) {

        customDialog = new CustomDialog(context);
        customDialog.show();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("id", id);
            object.put("cancel_reason", reason);
            Log.e("", "request_id" + id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLHelper.CANCEL_REQUEST_API, object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                customDialog.dismiss();
                utils.print("CancelRequestResponse", response.toString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.request_cancel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mapClear();
                clearVisibility();
                lnrGoOffline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                destinationLayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                CurrentStatus = "ONLINE";
                PreviousStatus = "NULL";
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                customDialog.dismiss();
                String json = null;
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                if (response != null && response.data != null) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject errorObj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));

                        if (response.statusCode == 400 || response.statusCode == 405 || response.statusCode == 500) {
                            try {
                                displayMessage(errorObj.optString("message"));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
                            GoToBeginActivity();
                        } else if (response.statusCode == 422) {

                            json = trimMessage(new String(response.data));
                            if (json != "" && json != null) {
                                displayMessage(json);
                            } else {
                                displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                            }
                        } else if (response.statusCode == 503) {
                            displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_down));
                        } else {
                            displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public java.util.Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + SharedHelper.getKey(context, "access_token"));
                Log.e("", "Access_Token" + SharedHelper.getKey(context, "access_token"));
                return headers;
            }
        };

        DriverApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    private void handleIncomingRequest(final String status, String id) {
        if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
            customDialog = new CustomDialog(activity);
            customDialog.show();
        }
        String url = URLHelper.base + "api/provider/trip/" + id;

        if (status.equals("Accept")) {
            method = Request.Method.POST;
        } else {
            method = Request.Method.DELETE;
        }

        final JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(method, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                if (customDialog != null)
                    customDialog.dismiss();
                if (status.equals("Accept")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.request_accept), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.i("timer","After on finish  "+timerCompleted +"");
                    if (!timerCompleted)
                        Toast.makeText(context, "" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.request_reject), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(context, "" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.request_time_out), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                customDialog.dismiss();
                utils.print("Error", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public java.util.Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        DriverApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }


    public void errorHandler(VolleyError error) {
        utils.print("Error", error.toString());
        String json = null;
        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
        if (response != null && response.data != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject errorObj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                utils.print("ErrorHandler", "" + errorObj.toString());
                if (response.statusCode == 400 || response.statusCode == 405 || response.statusCode == 500) {
                    try {
                        displayMessage(errorObj.optString("message"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
                    }
                } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
                    SharedHelper.putKey(context, "loggedIn", context.getResources().getString(R.string.False));
                    GoToBeginActivity();
                } else if (response.statusCode == 422) {
                    json = DriverApplication.trimMessage(new String(response.data));
                    if (json != "" && json != null) {
                        displayMessage(json);
                    } else {
                        displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                    }

                } else if (response.statusCode == 503) {
                    displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_down));
                } else {
                    displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
            }

        } else {
            displayMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_try_again));
        }
    }
```

And the error message that appears on the user application is **sorry_for_inconvinent**

```js
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                assert telephonyManager != null;
                boolean hasNetwork = telephonyManager.getNetworkType() != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
                if (hasNetwork) {
                    if (phone != null && !phone.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && !phone.equalsIgnoreCase("") && phone.length() > 0) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);
                        } else {
                            Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            intentCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                            startActivity(intentCall);
                        }
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setMessage(getString(R.string.**sorry_for_inconvinent**))
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("ok",
                                        (dialog, id) -> dialog.dismiss());
                        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                        alert1.show();
                    }
                }
```

My devs told me that the problem comes surely from the laravel server !

But the laravel log doesn't show any issue, they debug for weeks in vain!

Someone told me maybe it's because of the token expired
Another told me that the coordinates sent latitude and longitude are sometimes wrong

Can you help please ? i'm ready to share all the code if it helps to fix that bug.

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you check server logs? maybe problem is with server. server resources are not enough.

Comment: is there ant 503 or other logs in your web server logs? how much ram does your server have?

Comment: The dev put these lines at htaccess, not enough  ?  <IfModule php7_module>
   php_value memory_limit 400M
   php_value post_max_size 400M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 400M
   php_value max_execution_time 300
</IfModule>

Comment: yes I saw that. But for helping we need more information.

Comment: There is only one log :  /storage/logs/laravel.log  , i'm on vps, ram is 4GB

Comment: what is your web server?

Comment: debian 9 , php 7.0  , hosted on contabo.com

Comment: no I mean is that `nginx` or `apache` or ... and also depend on what is your web server, check your web server logs not laravel logs. if you didn't configure your your log path it may be in `/var/log` folder.

Comment: It's apache bro. Which logs i need to check ? there are a lot at /var/log.  Can you check yourself ? example i found this report at syslog, what do you think ?

Comment: so you should probably check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for any 5xx error. and also don't provide you production log files to public cause it can revel sensitive information. First check it yourself and just provide specific line or error that happened